# How can I get 32-bit program to run on 64-bit Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, 64-bit, 32-bit, multiarch

Sorry to be asking this, but I have read quite a few posts and articles a lot of places wrt the issue I am having, to no avail. I am trying to get a Second Life Viewer (Firestorm) to run, and just keep getting the '64-bit error message' it throws. I have installed every 32-lib I can find, still doesn't work. I think I am surely missing some setting somewhere, or running Firestorm from the wrong place, or something, but I have no idea what.

FWIW, Firestorm loads but doesn't behave right in the 32-bit version, either. I have actually tried several Linux distros, 32 and 64-bit. Mint 32-bit runs it straight off, and Mint 64-bit throws the '64-bit error'. openSUSE, any version, won't run it at all. Oh, and all the other SL viewers I have tried behave the same way.

I am beginning to wonder if my set-up just doesn't like Linux.

Here is my system info:

- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU 750 @ 2.67GHz (2661 MHz)
- Memory: 4026 MB
- OS Version: Linux 3.2.0-29-generic-pae #46-Ubuntu SMP i686
- Graphics Card Vendor: ATI Technologies Inc.
- Graphics Card: ATI Radeon HD 5700 Series

I appreciate any help anyone can give me!

Answer (score 4):

This shouldnt require any extra steps. 32 bit programs should run by default in a 64 bit environment with no issue, Of course the opposite is not true. If a 32 bit program wont run in your 64 bit system, I suspect there is a different issue. Try starting the program in terminal & watch for any errors. (strating a program in terminal simply requires  opening a terminal, typing the program name, & hit enter). If any errors appear, paste them in your question & I will try to help.